# Should I set timezone to convert string to date?

Tags: java, android, date-format, android-date

I convert string to date like this:

```
String date = Date_.get(position).substring(0,19); 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date testDate = null; 
try {   
    testDate = sdf.parse(date);
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

It works fine, But I am worry about should I need to set timezone? I mean there is a string I have like this: *'2014-01-01 00:00:00'* so why I  need to `settimezone` if it is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you should ... even to get rid of warning :D

you can you Locale.getDefault() like

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",Locale.getDefault());
```

also **TimeZone.getDefault()** ...

//EDIT

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    Date date = new Date();
    String defaultFmt = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(date);

    for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
        String localeFmt = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, locale).format(date);
        if (!localeFmt.equals(defaultFmt)) {
            System.out.println(locale + " " + localeFmt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, can I write this : 
**DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Istanbul"));**

Comment: so I do not need to write this **SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",Locale.getDefault());** right?

Comment: yes , you have to ... you can read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174696/how-locale-dependent-is-simpledateformat to understand why ...

Comment: sorry I cant understand I set timezone , why I must write locale.getdefault?

Comment: TimeZone has only to do with your position on the face of the Earth -- so that the time functions know how many hours to add to or subtract from GMT or UCT. Your Locale specifies how to format things like dates, numbers, etc.

Comment: ok but I need to set my date **Europe/Istanbul** how can I do that? because **Locale.getDefault()** is different in every country

Comment: I set the time with hour,minute,second in my template so why I need to write locale.getdefault

Comment: this in thailand your time in thailand local th_TH_TH ๒๕๕๔-๐๓-๐๓ ๑๖:๕๓:๐๙ ... do you get it why it is usefull ? :)

Comment: how can I set locale get time to TURKEY , because I cant find Locale.TURKEY

Comment: as i said above "Your Locale specifies how to format things like dates, numbers." ... i didment format like HH:mm:ss but how to interpret the numbers in it ...

Comment: see my edit ... you can find all available locales there :) choose as you want ...

Comment: so it isnot problem if I am in USA, or EUROPE or anywhere the time is same everywhere because I set the time template like 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to specify the time zone represented by that particular date-time string.

If you were talking to me on the phone, and you asked me what time it is, wouldn't you also ask me *where* I am? If I'm in Hawaii I'm going to tell you a different time than if I am in Paris.

The bundled java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Use either Joda-Time or the new java.time package in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310).

A Joda-Time DateTime object does indeed know its assigned time zone, whereas a java.util.Date has no time zone though its `toString` method applies the JVM's default time zone when generating as string.

## Joda-Time

Here is some example code using Joda-Time 2.3.

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();

// Convert a Date into a Joda-Time DateTime.
// Specify a time zone rather than rely on default.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Istanbul" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( date, timeZone );
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "date: " + date );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
```

When run…

```
date: Mon Mar 31 08:13:37 PDT 2014
dateTime: 2014-03-31T18:13:37.314+03:00
dateTimeUtc: 2014-03-31T15:13:37.314Z
```