# SimpleDateFormat throws ParseException With Error Offset 0

Tags: java, simpledateformat

What's wrong with the following code? It throws a ParseException with error offset 0.

```
final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy");
df.parse("Thu Jan 23 14:24:47 2014");
```

Comment: I've run the same code on my PC and there is no error.

Comment: This should work fine. Are you passing in the date string from some other place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't specify a `Locale` to the formatter when you construct it, it uses your default `Locale` which apparently doesn't spell days and months in English.

So specify one to the formatter that does.

```
final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", Locale.UK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your locale `"EN"`? If you use English names for the date, make sure you are using that locale

Answer (score 0):

[`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is absolutely locale-sensitive. Certain fields, like hours and minutes, are locale-independent.

> `SimpleDateFormat` also supports *localized date and time pattern* strings. In these strings, the pattern letters described above may be replaced with other, locale dependent, pattern letters. `SimpleDateFormat` does not deal with the localization of text other than the pattern letters; that's up to the client of the class.

Or, you can use the localization-friendly [`DateFormat#getDateInstance()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance%28int%2C%20java.util.Locale%29) factory method instead, since:

> `public SimpleDateFormat(String pattern, Locale locale)`
>
> Constructs a `SimpleDateFormat` using the given pattern and the default date format symbols for the given locale. Note: This constructor may not support all locales. For full coverage, use the factory methods in the [`DateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) class.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5174712/2591612

Answer (score 0):

### Never use `SimpleDateFormat` or `DateTimeFormatter` without a `Locale`

Since the given date-time is in English, you should use `Locale.ENGLISH` with your date-time parser; otherwise the parsing will fail in a system (computer, phone etc.) which is using a non-English type of locale.

Also, note that the date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String strDateTime = "Thu Jan 23 14:24:47 2014";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-01-23T14:24:47
```

By default, [`DateTimeFormatter#ofPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-) uses the [default FORMAT locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault-java.util.Locale.Category-) which the JVM sets during startup based on the host environment. Same is the case with [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String)). I have tried to illustrate the problem through the following demo:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String strDateTime = "Thu Jan 23 14:24:47 2014";          
        DateTimeFormatter dtfWithDefaultLocale = null;

        System.out.println("JVM's Locale: " + Locale.getDefault());
        // Using DateTimeFormatter with the default Locale
        dtfWithDefaultLocale = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss uuuu");         
        System.out.println("DateTimeFormatter's Locale: " + dtfWithDefaultLocale.getLocale());
        System.out.println(
                "Parsed with JVM's default locale: " + LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtfWithDefaultLocale));

        // Setting the JVM's default locale to Locale.FRANCE
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRANCE);
        
        // Using DateTimeFormatter with Locale.ENGLISH explicitly (recommended)
        DateTimeFormatter dtfWithEnglishLocale = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);        
        System.out.println("JVM's Locale: " + Locale.getDefault());
        System.out.println("DateTimeFormatter's Locale: " + dtfWithEnglishLocale.getLocale());
        LocalDateTime zdt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtfWithEnglishLocale);
        System.out.println("Parsed with Locale.ENGLISH: " + zdt);

        
        System.out.println("JVM's Locale: " + Locale.getDefault());
        // Using DateTimeFormatter with the default Locale
        dtfWithDefaultLocale = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss uuuu");         
        System.out.println("DateTimeFormatter's Locale: " + dtfWithDefaultLocale.getLocale());
        System.out.println(
                "Parsed with JVM's default locale: " + LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtfWithDefaultLocale));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
JVM's Locale: en_GB
DateTimeFormatter's Locale: en_GB
Parsed with JVM's default locale: 2014-01-23T14:24:47
JVM's Locale: fr_FR
DateTimeFormatter's Locale: en
Parsed with Locale.ENGLISH: 2014-01-23T14:24:47
JVM's Locale: fr_FR
DateTimeFormatter's Locale: fr_FR
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Thu Jan 23 14:24:47 2014' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at Main.main(Main.java:33)
```

---

**The following demo, using `SimpleDateFormat`, is just for the sake of completeness:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        final String strDateTime = "Thu Jan 23 14:24:47 2014";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = sdf.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Thu Jan 23 14:24:47 GMT 2014
```