# What causes some Java applications to run differently on some systems than others?

Tags: java, compatibility

I'm getting some reports of people having errors running my Java application, and I'm not experiencing the same errors. I'm pretty sure it's a problem on their end rather than an error in my code. What can cause an otherwise properly constructed Java application to not function right? Based on my testers' reports, they seem to have the latest Java update installed, and none of them are running Windows XP. What can I tell them to do in order to verify that Java is configured correctly on their system so that Java applications will run properly?

In the particular example I'm experiencing, I've written a GUI application for Windows. My tester is claiming that when he goes to the "File" menu and clicks "Open," nothing happens. On my end a JFileChooser window pops up, but for my tester nothing happens. We're both running 64-bit Windows 7 operating systems. I've tested this both with a Java update earlier than, and later than, what my tester is using. I also tried my application on another computer and it works fine on that one as well. I'm almost entirely convinced that it is an error on my user's end because I can't seem to get that same problem to occur.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: consider that there are lots of java versions. step 1: check which version they're using. If it's out of date, problem found.

Comment: What kind of errors are you talking about?

Comment: Consider that your code was not written in a cross platform way. For example, have you hard coded any `\r\n`? Also, have you considered that your code may actually have bugs?

Comment: How can you be sure the error is not in your code, if you do not know what exactly is causing it?

Comment: You always need to test your applications on at least one system other than your development one to declare your app to be really working.

Comment: For the example I'm experiencing, it's an application designed for Windows. Both myself and one of my testers are running it on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. I tested it on a Java update earlier than his, and then one later than his, and I'm still not getting the same errors. I've also tried it on another computer, and it's still working fine.

Comment: Also I apologize to those of you who thought this to be a poor question. I'll try to see if I can salvage it by providing more detail on my situation, but if not then forgive me for my newbish mistake.

Comment: I can only echo the other suggestions, tell us more about the type of application and type of error. Is it Gui, filesystem, data structure related?

Comment: It isn't actually an error, strictly speaking. It's simply the program not doing anything when it's supposed to. I was trying to generalize the question so that people could search this in the future and find this, but it seems my situation was more specific than I thought and thus required more specific detail. Sorry for my vagueness. I've edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: What's the log output when your tester hits the "Open" button? Is there maybe an exception thrown?

Answer (score 3):

> What can cause an otherwise properly constructed Java application to not function right.

That is a circular question.  And the only possible answer is a circular answer.

But some of the more common things include.

- Accidental incorporation of platform specific assumptions into the code:

  - Assuming that a particular platform syntax for pathnames, end of lines.
  - Assuming platform specific file system layouts.
  - Assuming that the application will be run with admin permissions.
  - Assuming a specific character encoding scheme for text.
- Threading issues.  Incorrectly written multi-threaded code can appear to run correctly on one platform (with a given OS and hardware configuration) and be unreliable on another.  Beware that GUI based applications in Java are often multi-threaded.
- Security related issues.  There have been significant (breaking!) changes in the way that applets and the like are handled in recent Java releases.

Based on the fact that different testers are reporting different problems, and (I'm guessing) the bug reports don't seem to make sense, I would suspect multi-threading / synchronization problems.

---

> What can I tell them to do in order to verify that Java is configured correctly on their system so that Java applications will run properly?

It is unlikely to be a problem with the way that Java is installed. Especially if multiple testers are reporting problems.

The problem is most likely in your application, and your assumption that it is properly constructed.

Answer (score 2):

It would be great if you described the error your clients are getting in more detail.

Until then I'll wager a stab in the dark and say the client's locale is different than yours and your code is not locale independent.

Maybe you used `String#toLowerCase()` and now everything crashes because [your clients are Turkish](http://java.sys-con.com/node/46241).

Or you overlooked that `SimpleDateFormat` is [locale dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174696/how-locale-dependent-is-simpledateformat).

Edit:

```
I'm almost entirely convinced that it is an error on my user's end
```

I invite you to get rid of that conviction and assume a more humble stance towards your code. [Because our skulls are so small.](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD03xx/EWD340.html)